# correct way of storing data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a many json outputs like below. Instead of storing these json as a file, I want to store them into mongodb! I am a new to mongodb and my question is should I store each file as a collection? or should each file be a document?
Filenames are unique, and can generally be divided into two main types of file  (e.g., x-value.json & y-value.json).

Mapping to mysql, each json file is a row in my mysql database! and columns are values like *files_dropped*

```
        {
            "attributes": {
                "analysis_date": 1579287037,
                "command_executions": [
                    "C:\Program Files\Synchronization\rastlsc.exe"
                    
                ],
                "files_dropped": [
                    {
                        "path": "\Program Files\Synchronization\rastls.dll" }
                ],
               
        {
            "attributes": {
                "analysis_date": 1579328273,
                "crypto_algorithms_observed": [
                    "AES"
                ],
                "files_deleted": [
                    "C:\Documents and Settings\nssB.tmp"
                ]
                "has_evtx": false,
                "has_html_report": true
                },
            {
            "attributes": {
                "analysis_date": 1579644008,
                "processes_created": [
                    "C:\DOCUMENT\Installer.exe"
                ]
                
            },
            {
            "attributes": {
                "analysis_date": 1579263621,
                "calls_highlighted": [
                    "SetFileTime"
                ],
                "command_executions": [
                    "C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Temp\Installer.exe"
                ],
                "has_html_report": true,
                "has_mem": false,
                "last_modification_date": 1579263621,
                "modules_loaded": [
                    "ADVAPI32.dll"]
            }
```

Comment: The logic here can be analogous to tables in SQL, so if you're familiar with it, you can replace "collection" with "table" and see if that helps to answer the question. Otherwise, it all depends on the context. If each file has a different structure or represents a different data category, you should store them as separate collections. On the other hand, if the files contain the same structure and fall into the same category, you can merge them into one collection.

Comment: Good point! each of these json files are a row in my mysql database!

Comment: How data is stored is dependent upon many factors. Mainly, how you are going to use or query that stored data? Other factors are, size of the document, number of documents, etc. This is about database design.

Answer (score 0):

My sense is that these should be in a single collection.  Let's call it `info` although the name is arbitrary.  `info` will contain many docs in this shape.  Notes:

1. _id can be anything; perfectly fine to let the client-side driver make it up upon insert.
2. It looks like `analysis_date` is a common required field.  "Promote" it to root level -- and let's make it a real mongodb datetime type as well.
3. `attributes` can have essentially any required attributes; this is the power of polymorphism in mongodb.

```js
 {
    _id: 0,
    "analysis_date":   ISODate("2020-01-17T18:50:37Z")
    "attributes": {
                "command_executions": [
                    "C:\Program Files\Synchronization\rastlsc.exe"
                    
                ],
                "files_dropped": [
                    {
                        "path": "\Program Files\Synchronization\rastls.dll" }
                ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `analysis_date` is an optional field, so it can be absent in some json files. But `attributes` is a common field and present in all json and is  somehow the root. but the problem is the whole json file which includes many attribute forms my records in  tables in mysql db, AND i have several millions of those files.  So it doesn't make sense to make each file a collection, if we consider collections are somehow tables in mysql!

Comment: Def NOT each file a collection; I am suggesting a *single* collection for millions of docs.